# Getting HttpErrorResponse error in angular for Delete request

Tags: python, angular, typescript

I am trying to send a Delete request from my movie.component.ts page to delete a review. But I am getting HttpErrorResponse error. Where am I going wrong?

here is a screenshot of the error message I am receiving in the console:
[HttpErrorResponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrOG0.png)

**movie.component.ts**

```
 deleteReview(reviewID: any) {
    this.webService.deleteReview(reviewID).subscribe((res) => {
      alert('Review deleted');
    });
  }
```

**web.service.ts**

```
deleteReview(id: any) {
    return this.http.delete(
      'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/movies' + id + '/reviews/' + this.reviewID
    );
  }
```

Here is my back-end Delete method

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/movies/<string:id>/reviews/<string:reviewID>", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_review(id, reviewID):
    movies.update_one(
        {"_id": ObjectId(id)},
        {"$pull": {"reviews": {"_id": ObjectId(reviewID)}}}
    )
    return make_response(jsonify({}), 204)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594893/how-to-enable-cors-in-flask)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517054/allow-cors-to-flask-endpoint

Comment: I have "from flask_cors import CORS" and "CORS(app)" in my app.py

Answer (score 0):

Typo in web.service.ts. Forgot a slash after `/reviews/`. Second a typo on this.reviewID**w**.
So in your error you see the value of reviewID is undefined. This can bring this CORS error, too. Then the route was not found.

Greetings Florian

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have corrected the typos but still getting the same error message.